# Excel reference named range with text and formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, named-ranges

Is it possible to refer to a named range by combining text with a formula?  Say I get a name for a range via INDEX which returns a text but I also want to add something after the text like so:

> RANGE & "Whatever comes after"

I have several named ranges so in order to dynamically refer to those ranges I need to add something after that RANGE text.  Excel however gives an error.

In a nutshell

Named ranges:

RANGE1
RANGE2
RANGE3 etc.

What I want is say with a count formula:

```
=COUNTIF(RANGE & "whatever comes after",1)
```

If I try to do this then Excel gives an error so is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14856889/2088851) help you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap it all in an `INDIRECT` function. INDIRECT translates a string into a reference.

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("RANGE" & "whatever comes after"),1)
```

Answer (score 2):

As Voitcus indicated, try the INDIRECT command to build the query string.  The range part should look something line:

```
indirect(RANGE & "whatever comes after")
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the ",1" in your COUNTIF statement but try:

```
=countif(indirect(range & "whatever comes after"),1)
```